# I'm going CRAZY: ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/private/etc/php-fpm.conf' homebrew

Tags: macos, nginx, php

I was able to successfully install php54 with fpm and with mysql onto my system. However, when I try to start the server by running `php-fpm` in terminal I get an error saying...

```
1.ERROR: failed to open configuration file '/private/etc/php-fpm.conf': No such file or directory (2)

2.ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/private/etc/php-fpm.conf'

3.ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

However, my `php-fpm.conf` file is located in this directory: `/usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php-fpm.conf`. I'm not really sure what to do at this point. I'm going crazy and could use help out there. Can anyone point me in the right direction. I am running the latest version of Mountain Lion and have installed the latest command line tools.

Answer (score 16):

The php-fpm binary expects php-fpm.conf file to read the configuration when it starts up. On Mac OSX by default this file is named as "/private/etc/php-fpm.conf.default" Change/copy it to "php-fpm.conf" from "php-fpm.conf.default"

```
cp /private/etc/php-fpm.conf.default /private/etc/php-fpm.conf
```

And then restart the service

Comment: That helped, so +1, but now I get `ERROR: failed to open error_log (/usr/var/log/php-fpm.log): No such file or directory (2)`.

Comment: Can you touch that file? Make sure permissions are right

Comment: This was vital for me

Answer (score 0):

you can start by brew if you installed by brew.

1. be sure closed php-fpm

   `sudo killall php-fpm`
2. start by brew

   `brew services start php`